# How do I exclude rows in SQL where string does not contain two words

Tags: sql

Example table to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE example
    (name varchar(200)
     
    );

INSERT INTO example
(name)
VALUES
('ab'),
('ab|test'),
('test');
```

SQL query:

```
select
name
from example
where name not like '%ab%' and  name not like '%test%'
```

This returns 0

What I am looking to do is to first exclude any rows where the name column contains *both* 'ab' and 'test' and then return the rest.  In this case it should return row 1 and row 3.

To add - in production the name column has around 300k records so I need to filter by exclusion instead of inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want OR

```
.. not (name like '%ab%' and name like '%test%')
```

this is the same as

```
select
name
from example
where name not like '%ab%' OR  name not like '%test%
```

Comment: why does  name not like '%ab%' not exclude the row where name = 'ab' ?

Comment: Because of OR. Only both words present row will make the condition FALSE. If any word is missing condition is TRUE.

Comment: @Austin , .. good point.  To correct it we need to know what are the possible word delimiters.

Comment: Thats fine to ignore words that contain those values.  @Serg I thought OR returns 'TRUE' if one OR the other value is present. And logic returns TRUE if both values are present. My mind is blown haha

Comment: @NickEdwards,  you can just try and see. )

Comment: It works but it feels strange that an OR is what I need! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The operator `LIKE` as you use it, does not check if the pattern exists as a whole word in the column `name`. It could be part of the word.

Assuming that the words in the column `name` do not contain `','`, you should use the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to safely check if a word exists in the column's value:

```
SELECT name
FROM example
WHERE NOT (
  FIND_IN_SET('ab', REPLACE(name, '|', ',')) 
  AND 
  FIND_IN_SET('test', REPLACE(name, '|', ','))
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e64561fbf63082c78f87b3617e2928b).

Answer (score 0):

Use `len()` function

```
select e.* from example e where len(name) > 2
```

Comment: There are other values in the column which are also greater > 2. I have not included all 300k records in my example. Sorry I should have flagged that earlier. I am looking to exclude based on the string containing two specific words...